# Obtaining last node of BST from an iterator returned by end() function?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, binary-search-tree

I'm struggling to understand implementation requirements for the end() function which returns an iterator pointing one past the last element. What does one past last element mean? Isn't it always going to be null? And if it holds no information then how can I get to the final node of BST with O(1) time complexity with the help of end()?

Comment: There's no standard BST container. Did you mean `std::set`?

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own container for BST. It's a college assignment.

Comment: You should have said so from the beginning. Have you looked at any existing implementations so far?

Comment: I checked few but couldn't understand much, I found them to be really complex, I don't really have that much time to figure out how they function. I am trying to design rather basic and simple solution for the purpose of assignment.

Comment: I've a pointer to parent along with left and right for nodes in BST. So I somehow need to make the node pointed to by iterator returned by end() function point to the last element in BST. What I get from your answer is that I need to create one more node which is logically not in BST but  serves to track the last node of BST.

Comment: is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684191/implementing-an-iterator-over-binary-or-arbitrary-tree-using-c-11 relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a "null" element etc. is something that simply doesn't figure in the iterator semantics. It's literally meaningless. Iterators aren't raw C pointers.

It's on you to design your iterators such that `end()-1` on a non-empty container returns the final node, if the iterator is [bidirectional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) to start with.

For the more general case of a forward iterator, all that you really wish is that *some* iterator equals `end()` when it's been incremented one past the last element, or `begin() == end()` when there are no elements.

This is sometimes done by having `end()` point to a special node that only exists to facilitate `end()`'s functionality.

An iterator could store a boolean field indicating whether it's the result of `end()`, for example. Iterators can hold as much information as you desire. It's an optimization to lower that amount, but an optional one.

Nobody forces you, of course, for `begin()` and `end()` to be the only available means of obtaining an iterator.